# How to limit match length before a certain character?

Tags: regex, perl

I am using the following regular expression to scan input text files for valid emails.

```
[A-Za-z0-9!#$%&*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[A-Za-z0-9!#$%&*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@(?:[A-Za-z0-9](?:[A-Za-z0-9-]*[A-Za-z0-9])?\.)+[A-Za-z0-9](?:[A-Za-z0-9-]*[A-Za-z0-9])?
```

Now I also need to limit the matches to 20 characters before the '@' sign in the email address, but not sure how to do it.

PS. I am using the Perl regular expression library (TPerlRegex) found in Delphi XE2.

Please can you help me?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since your library is supposed to be PERL compatible, it should support [lookaheads](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html). These are convenient to ensure several "orthogonal" restrictions in the pattern:

```
(?=[^@]{1,20}@)[A-Za-z0-9!#$%&*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[A-Za-z0-9!#$%&*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@(?:[A-Za-z0-9](?:[A-Za-z0-9-]*[A-Za-z0-9])?\.)+[A-Za-z0-9](?:[A-Za-z0-9-]*[A-Za-z0-9])?
```

The lookahead will only match if there is an `@` after no more than 20 non-`@` characters. However, the lookahead does not actually advance the position of the regex engine in your subject string, so after the condition has been checked, the engine is still at the beginning of the email (or whichever position it is checking at the moment) and will continue with your pattern as previously.

Answer (score 2):

Consider using [Email::Address](http://search.cpan.org/~rjbs/Email-Address-1.898/lib/Email/Address.pm) to capture email addresses, and then `grep`ping the results for those having 20 or fewer characters before the `@`:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Email::Address;

my @addresses;

while ( my $line = <DATA> ) {
    push @addresses, $_
      for grep { /([^@]+)/ and length $1 < 21 }
      Email::Address->parse($line);
}

print "$_\n" for @addresses;

__DATA__
ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZguest@host.com frank@email.net Line noise. test@host.com
Some stuff here... help@perl.org And even more here!
Nothing to see here.  01234567890123456789@numbers.com  Nothing to see.
```

Output:

```
frank@email.net
test@host.com
help@perl.org
01234567890123456789@numbers.com
```

Comment: This looks like a good solution, except that OP seems to be using Delphi, not Perl.

Comment: @amon - Thank you.  I overlooked the use of Delphi.  ps - I always appreciate seeing your work here...